# Using pingpong/widget in Laravel throws an error

Tags: php, laravel, widget

I'm using the laravel's package

> "pingpong/widget": "~2.1",

I've set the configuration in `config\app.php`

Added

```
Pingpong\Widget\WidgetServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Widget'    => Pingpong\Widget\WidgetFacade::class,
```

And as in the documentation, i'm using this code to create a widget:

```
use Pingpong\Widget\Widget;

Widget::register('small', function($contents)
{
    return "<small>{$contents}</small>";
});
```

But I got this error:

```
Non-static method Pingpong\Widget\Widget::register() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

In the Pingpong\Widget\Widget class, there are no static functions, so of course this error is expected. But... how we can create a widget then, when all sample codes in the documentation are using static classes and in the Widget class, there are no static methods? Am I missing something?

Creating a widget object and calling the `->register()` on it also throw an error, because creating a widget expects `BladeCompiler $blade, Container $container` in the `_construct` method and I have no idea what to pass here.

Any ideas on what could be wrong with this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `use Pingpong\Widget\Widget;` to just `use Widget;`

Laravel, and some packages, include Facades to facilitate easy usage of some components. While everything looks like a static call, the static call on the facade actually maps to a non-static call on a concrete object that is masked by the facade. So, when you're attempting `Widget::register()`, the facade looks up the concrete instance it has of the `Widget` class, and then calls the `register()` method on that instance non-statically.

In your `config/app.php` file, you've added the `Widget` alias which points to the `WidgetFacade`. This alias is created in the base namespace. If you would like to use this alias to the facade, you need to just reference the `Widget` alias in the base namespace (i.e. `use Widget;`).

By stating `use Pingpong\Widget\Widget;`, your `Widget::register()` call is trying to call a static `register()` method on the `Pingpong\Widget\Widget` class, instead of the method on the facade.

Comment: Tried it but I got `The use statement with non-compound name 'Widget' has no effect`

Comment: @IvanMilanov Is the file that you're adding the `use` statement in a namespace? Can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I just forgot to add the namespace of the file, where the Widget was. Thanks.